# C++ / Arduino separate server from setup

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm not sure how to explain this, or what the technical term is here, but I simply want to be able to move my server logic and functions into their own file (separate from the setup / loop / main file).

For example:

```
//App.cpp

#include "WebServer.h"

WebServer server(80);

void handleRoute() {};
void setup() {
    server.on("/", handleRoute);
}
```

I basically want all my server code and handler functions to be in a separate file.  I tried subclassing the WebServer class but then I couldn't get access to some of its member functions.  I'm a cpp newb, so what's the standard way of abstracting or delegating this to its own library or set of free functions?  As you can imagine, this is a contrived example, and in reality I have several handlers and they are simply cluttering up the App.cpp file and the namespace.

Comment: A better question would perhaps be to actually provide your code example and find out the reason why it doesn't work: that way you learn something that, supposedly, you don't know now. But to answer your question, you could try wrapping the instance in a completely new class, that shouldn't be hard. This is a bit of too broadquestion for *StackOverflow* though, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickTrentin, I'm reluctant to post all 500 lines, because it literally looks like what I abstracted above, but 490 lines more. =)   I like the idea of wrapping the instance in a new class, can you explain how you do that in cpp?

Comment: Why should 500 lines be necesary? *"I tried subclassing the WebServer class but then I coudln't get access to some of its member functions"*: a minimal complete verifiable example shouldn't take more than 50 lines. Perhaps I misunderstand the issue..?